# Changing the MHS file in xilinx EDK 14.4 adding a port in the uart peripharal

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-edk

I am trying to add a port in the uart created by xilinx-EDK (hardware design in the EDK of the hardware setup I have), I got to know by changing the MHS file I can add a port. but whenever I change the the MHS file it shows an error that i can not add a port as It is not there in the MPD file, and project closes in xilinx EDK.

My setup: I have xc6slx9 2 csg324 fpga. i have rs232 uart which has three port RX, TX, SW. but the default design created by Xilinx EDk only has TX and RX port on the uart so i need to add SW port. I am writing the MHS file.

```
# ##############################################################################
# Created by Base System Builder Wizard for Xilinx EDK 14.4 Build EDK_P.49d
# Mon Mar 03 09:02:22 2014
# Target Board:  Custom
# Family:    spartan6
# Device:    xc6slx9
# Package:   csg324
# Speed Grade:  -2
# ##############################################################################
 PARAMETER VERSION = 2.1.0


 PORT RS232_Uart_1_sout = RS232_Uart_1_sout, DIR = O
 PORT RS232_Uart_1_sin = RS232_Uart_1_sin, DIR = I
 PORT RESET = RESET, DIR = I, SIGIS = RST, RST_POLARITY = 1
# PORT CLK_P = CLK, DIR = I, DIFFERENTIAL_POLARITY = P, SIGIS = CLK, CLK_FREQ = 100000000
# PORT CLK_N = CLK, DIR = I, DIFFERENTIAL_POLARITY = N, SIGIS = CLK, CLK_FREQ = 100000000
 PORT CLK = CLK, DIR = I, SIGIS = CLK, CLK_FREQ = 27000000
 PORT TX_enable = TX_enable, DIR = O   # I am trying to add this port 


BEGIN proc_sys_reset
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = proc_sys_reset_0
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 3.00.a
 PARAMETER C_EXT_RESET_HIGH = 1
 PORT MB_Debug_Sys_Rst = proc_sys_reset_0_MB_Debug_Sys_Rst
 PORT Dcm_locked = proc_sys_reset_0_Dcm_locked
 PORT MB_Reset = proc_sys_reset_0_MB_Reset
 PORT Slowest_sync_clk = clk_100_0000MHz
 PORT Interconnect_aresetn = proc_sys_reset_0_Interconnect_aresetn
 PORT Ext_Reset_In = RESET
 PORT BUS_STRUCT_RESET = proc_sys_reset_0_BUS_STRUCT_RESET
END

BEGIN lmb_v10
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = microblaze_0_ilmb
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 2.00.b
 PORT SYS_RST = proc_sys_reset_0_BUS_STRUCT_RESET
 PORT LMB_CLK = clk_100_0000MHz
END

BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = microblaze_0_i_bram_ctrl
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 3.10.c
 PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x00000000
 PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x00003fff
 BUS_INTERFACE SLMB = microblaze_0_ilmb
 BUS_INTERFACE BRAM_PORT = microblaze_0_i_bram_ctrl_2_microblaze_0_bram_block
END

BEGIN lmb_v10
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = microblaze_0_dlmb
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 2.00.b
 PORT SYS_RST = proc_sys_reset_0_BUS_STRUCT_RESET
 PORT LMB_CLK = clk_100_0000MHz
END

BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = microblaze_0_d_bram_ctrl
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 3.10.c
 PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x00000000
 PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x00003fff
 BUS_INTERFACE SLMB = microblaze_0_dlmb
 BUS_INTERFACE BRAM_PORT = microblaze_0_d_bram_ctrl_2_microblaze_0_bram_block
END

BEGIN bram_block
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = microblaze_0_bram_block
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 1.00.a
 BUS_INTERFACE PORTA = microblaze_0_i_bram_ctrl_2_microblaze_0_bram_block
 BUS_INTERFACE PORTB = microblaze_0_d_bram_ctrl_2_microblaze_0_bram_block
END

BEGIN microblaze
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = microblaze_0
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 8.40.b
 PARAMETER C_INTERCONNECT = 2
 PARAMETER C_USE_BARREL = 1
 PARAMETER C_USE_FPU = 0
 PARAMETER C_DEBUG_ENABLED = 1
 PARAMETER C_ICACHE_BASEADDR = 0X00000000
 PARAMETER C_ICACHE_HIGHADDR = 0X3FFFFFFF
 PARAMETER C_USE_ICACHE = 0
 PARAMETER C_ICACHE_ALWAYS_USED = 0
 PARAMETER C_DCACHE_BASEADDR = 0X00000000
 PARAMETER C_DCACHE_HIGHADDR = 0X3FFFFFFF
 PARAMETER C_USE_DCACHE = 0
 PARAMETER C_DCACHE_ALWAYS_USED = 0
 BUS_INTERFACE ILMB = microblaze_0_ilmb
 BUS_INTERFACE DLMB = microblaze_0_dlmb
 BUS_INTERFACE M_AXI_DP = axi4lite_0
 BUS_INTERFACE DEBUG = microblaze_0_debug
 PORT MB_RESET = proc_sys_reset_0_MB_Reset
 PORT CLK = clk_100_0000MHz
END

BEGIN mdm
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = debug_module
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 2.10.a
 PARAMETER C_INTERCONNECT = 2
 PARAMETER C_USE_UART = 1
 PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x41400000
 PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x4140ffff
 BUS_INTERFACE S_AXI = axi4lite_0
 BUS_INTERFACE MBDEBUG_0 = microblaze_0_debug
 PORT Debug_SYS_Rst = proc_sys_reset_0_MB_Debug_Sys_Rst
 PORT S_AXI_ACLK = clk_100_0000MHz
END

BEGIN clock_generator
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = clock_generator_0
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 4.03.a
 PARAMETER C_CLKIN_FREQ = 27000000
 PARAMETER C_CLKOUT0_FREQ = 1687500
 PARAMETER C_CLKOUT0_GROUP = NONE
 PORT LOCKED = proc_sys_reset_0_Dcm_locked
 PORT CLKOUT0 = clk_100_0000MHz
 PORT RST = RESET
 PORT CLKIN = CLK
END

BEGIN axi_interconnect
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = axi4lite_0
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 1.06.a
 PARAMETER C_INTERCONNECT_CONNECTIVITY_MODE = 0
 PORT interconnect_aclk = clk_100_0000MHz
 PORT INTERCONNECT_ARESETN = proc_sys_reset_0_Interconnect_aresetn
END

BEGIN axi_uartlite
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = RS232
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 1.02.a
 PARAMETER C_BAUDRATE = 9600
 PARAMETER C_DATA_BITS = 8
 PARAMETER C_USE_PARITY = 0
 PARAMETER C_ODD_PARITY = 1
 PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x40600000
 PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x4060ffff
 BUS_INTERFACE S_AXI = axi4lite_0
 PORT S_AXI_ACLK = clk_100_0000MHz
 PORT TX = RS232_Uart_1_sout
 PORT RX = RS232_Uart_1_sin
 PORT TX_enable = RS232_TX_enable # I am trying to add this port 
END
```

/////////////// ANSWER OF MY QUESTION /////////////////

It's easy to add a port which is not connected to any ipcore.
Just use the lines:

```
PORT TX_enable = net_vcc, DIR = O
```

Comment: Why are you hand-editing the MHS file?  Sure it's possible, but you do end up having to read the docs on how it works.  Just use the EDK tools to add your extra ports.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add a port to a pcore (such as the `axi_uartlite`) in the MHS file.

The ports on a pcore are defined by the MPD file for that core.  For Xilinx pcores the MPD files can be found in:

`[Xilinx_Install_Dir]\ISE_DS\EDK\hw\XilinxProcessorIPLib\pcores\`

If you look at the MPD file for the axi_uartlite, `TX_ENABLE` is not a port that is available.

Comment: I will not add a port to a pcore, actually I will just create an external port and set it's value to net_vcc for high value or net_gnd for low which I needed for my application. The problem has been solved I understood how to add a port, the port will not belong to any of the pcore.